# How to set directory owner group with Java NIO createDirectories method?

Tags: java, java-8, nio

I am using Java createDirectories method to create sub ditrctories inside test directory, and setting file permissions. Below is the code;

```
String completeDestPath = "/home/base/test/test1/test2/test3/";
Path destinationPath = Paths.get(completeDestPath);

Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx");
FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> fa = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms);

Files.createDirectories(destinationPath, fa);
```

This is working fine. Along with this, i want to set file owner group to newly created ditrctories. For this, I use the below code;

```
UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
GroupPrincipal group = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByGroupName("testgroup_1");

Files.getFileAttributeView(destinationPath, PosixFileAttributeView.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).setGroup(group);
```

But here, i need to call the code in a loop, or recursive to get each newly created ditrctories and then change owner group. Is it possible to do this in a better way, like passing as argument to createDirectories method?

Comment: Did you try `Files.createDirectories(destinationPath, new FileAttribute<GroupPrincipal>() { public String name() { return "posix:group"; } public GroupPrincipal value() { return group; } });`?

Comment: Looking over the API, it now seems to me that setting the group right on file creation is not supported at all.